# Fontspec and Microsoft Store fonts on Windows 10

Tags: miktex, fontspec, windows

As of April 2018, Windows 10 now installs some fonts through the Microsoft Store or Microsoft Office.  These fonts are not installed in the usual font folder `C:\Windows\Fonts`, but instead in protected folders under `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`.  The `fontspec` package can't search this path, so the fonts cannot be used.

Does anyone have a work-around?

Here's a MNWE, compiled with XeLaTeX in the MikTeX package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Georgia Pro}
\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

The `Georgia Pro` font is indeed installed on my machine, as I can use it from within Windows-native apps.  Older fonts, such as `Georgia` load without problems.

Comment: According to this you can install such fonts in your fonts folder: https://geekermag.com/windows-store-fonts-location/. Beside this it is not a fontspec question but (for xelatex) of the fontconfig setting and you should better ask in the miktex issue tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the path to your fonts to your `localfonts2.conf` file. This can be found in `C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\fontconfig\config` and/or `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fontconfig\config`.

Comment: This doesn't directly work because the folder doesn't have read permission by default. Also, each font is in a separate folder, so this is cumbersome.

Comment: Follow [this guide](https://www.maketecheasier.com/access-windowsapps-folder-windows-10/) to take ownership of the WindowsApps folder. You might have to repeat it for the WindowsApps\Deleted folder. This solution works after that (on my machine at least). You don't need to add each font folder, just WindowsApps is enough.